# jQuery each count issue

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to display count within the 'dt' wrap of each person but at the moment its displaying count between everyone in and outside the 'dt' wrap. I've attached a screen print. if anyone can advice me on this fix I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
 $('.order_table_item .variation dt').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == 'Candidate Name:') {
            $(this).next().show();
            $(this).before("<div class='count'></div>");
            $(this).next().after("<div class='clear'></div>");

        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });

    $('.variation .count').each(function(i) {
            $(this).append((i+1));
    });
```

[image]

I tried,

```
$('.order_table_item').each(function(i,e){


    $('.variation .count').each(function(i) {
            $(this).append((i+1));
    });

});
```

and now its doubling up the numbers,

[image]

The cleaned up shorted down version of my html,

```
  <table class="shop_table order_details">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="order_table_item">
            <td class="product-name"> 
                <dl class="variation">
                    <div class="count" style="border-top: 0px none;">11</div>
                    <dd style="display: block; border-top: 0px none;">Dave</dd>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </dl>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="order_table_item">
            <td class="product-name">
                <dl class="variation">
                    <div class="count">22</div>
                    <dd style="display: block;">JACK</dd>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="count">33</div>
                    <dd style="display: block;">JOHN</dd>
                </dl>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: show us your html code as well

Comment: $('.variation .count') change it to $('.variation dt .count');

Comment: On your fiddle, should the output go: 111, 221, 332?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7DxVJ/1/

### JQuery

```
$('.variation').each(function(x) {
    $(this).find('.count').each(function(i) {
        $(this).append(i+1);
    });
});
```

Outputs:

> 111 Dave
>
> 221 JACK
>
> 332 JOHN

Answer (score 0):

Since i dont know exactly how your code looks like, i have three ideas:

Idea 1:

```
$('.variation .count').each(function(i) {
  $(this).text(i+1);
});
```

Idea 2: Since "1" + 1 = 11, try to parse the i so it becomes an int instead of a string.

```
$('.variation .count').each(function(i) {
  $(this).append(parseint(i)+1);
});
```

Idea 3:

```
$('.variation .count').each(function(index) { //i is already taken, better to use another variable here.
  $(this).text(index+1);
});
```

Idea 4: Since you are inside an each-loop, which i missed, you probably want to loop through each of its .count, not all .count everytime.

```
$('.order_table_item').each(function(i,e){
  $(this).find('.variation .count').each(function(index) { //use $(this) to loop every .count inside .order_table_item.
    $(this).text(index+1);
  });
});
```

[See working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RhDFd/)

Comment: I tried all of these and they all output the same issue, the either repeat the number e.g 11 ,22 ,33 or it goes 1,2,3 from div to div instead of going box one 1, box two 1,2,3. I've added my html above if they is anything else you can see please let me know.